# Flutter format & align ClipRRect text

Tags: flutter

Im developing a dating app style program in flutter. I currently have 5 keywords being displayed at the bottom of the page. Im using ClipRRect's so that the words appear within a rounded rectangle background. It's really bugging me that the keywords wont align up with the name and bio above. Also there is no space between the top and bottom row of keywords, they sort of blend into one and it doesn't look very professional. Is anyone able to offer any advice please?
Thank you!

```
  Widget buildKeywords() => Container(
    child: Wrap(
      alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        child: Text(
          "  "+widget.user.keyword1+"  ",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(195, 245, 172, 132)),
        ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width:4,height:10),
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        child: Text(
          "  "+widget.user.keyword2+"  ",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(195, 245, 172, 132)),
        ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width:4,height:10),
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        child: Text(
          "  "+widget.user.keyword3+"  ",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(195, 245, 172, 132)),
        ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width:4,height:10),
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        child: Text(
          "  "+widget.user.keyword4+"  ",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(195, 245, 172, 132)),
        ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width:4,height:10),
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        child: Text(
          "  "+widget.user.keyword5+"  ",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(195, 245, 172, 132)),
        ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

[image]